# Arrays in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Can any one explain how to store array in datadase ?

```
ID       NAME        ARRAY_FIELD
1        John        (CRICKET DANCE)
2        Wright      (BOOKS HOCKEY)
```

How can i store in table like above manner .

Comment: are you using php with mysql?

Comment: No Raheel just mysql data dase only

Answer (score 0):

An array cannot be stored in a database. That's the reason why many programmers use a serialize() function so the array gets transformed into a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert into field with comma separated values while again getting these value explode then with comma and process them further

INSERT INTO (ARRAY_FIELD) TABLE VALUES('CRICKET,DANCE');